# Can't hide ProgressBar with DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

It's been a year since I used DataBinding last time. It seems something has changed since then or I've made a stupid mistake. Let's look at my problem.

**UPD:** please, also check the first comment

**Long story short**

[image]

I have a simple ProgressBar in my project:

```xml
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="/path/to/.SignInViewModel" />
</data>

<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout

        <ProgressBar
            ...
            android:visibility="@{vm.signInProgress ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    
</layout>
```

which is visible on the screen until I press the button:

```kotlin
binding.login.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.signInProgress.value = false
}
```

where signInProgress is just a MutableLiveData

```kotlin
val signInProgress: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
```

That's all about my interaction with ProgressBar. BUT when I click on login button, my ProgressBar  becomes invisible for only a second, then it appears again and begins to rotate. Whaaaaat?

Also I checked generated Binding file and it seems like everything is fine:

```kotlin
androidxDatabindingViewDataBindingSafeUnboxVmSignInProgressGetValue = androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.safeUnbox(vmSignInProgressGetValue);
if(androidxDatabindingViewDataBindingSafeUnboxVmSignInProgressGetValue) {
    dirtyFlags |= 0x10L;
} else {
    dirtyFlags |= 0x8L;
}
vmSignInProgressViewVISIBLEViewGONE = ((androidxDatabindingViewDataBindingSafeUnboxVmSignInProgressGetValue) ? (android.view.View.VISIBLE) : (android.view.View.GONE));
if ((dirtyFlags & 0x7L) != 0) {
    this.loginProgress.setVisibility(vmSignInProgressViewVISIBLEViewGONE);
}
```

**Fragment:**

```kotlin
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
binding.vm = viewModel
```

**Gradle**

```
// app
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}
// project
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
```

Can you help me to understand, what's going on here? I can't understand, why it can't just hide? It's my personal project, so I can share a link if you want to help me :(

Comment: Ok, when I do smth like this: binding.progress.isVisible = false by click - same story

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the cause of the problem, but I haven't find a solution yet. Problem in my MotionLayout (I created the same layout with ConstraintLayout), but I wonder why